# Thread 4: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x118)

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

i am using alamofire then i am getting crash in ResponceSerealization.Swift here[image]

```
       @discardableResult
```

its crashing in pod 'alamofire'and not giving and crash detail in log

```
        public func response<T: DataResponseSerializerProtocol>(
        queue: DispatchQueue? = nil,
        responseSerializer: T,
        completionHandler: @escaping (DataResponse<T.SerializedObject>) -> Void)
        -> Self
    {
        delegate.queue.addOperation {
            let result = responseSerializer.serializeResponse(
                self.request,
                self.response,
                self.delegate.data,
                self.delegate.error
            )

            var dataResponse = DataResponse<T.SerializedObject>(
                request: self.request,
                response: self.response,
                data: self.delegate.data,
                result: result,
                timeline: self.timeline
            )

            dataResponse.add(self.delegate.metrics)

            (queue ?? DispatchQueue.main).async { completionHandler(dataResponse) }
        }

        return self
    }
}
```

Comment: post your crash log, and add your code as text

Comment: its crashing in pods i have add code see above